# How to add table item in AjaxToolkit Html Editor?

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have used AjaxToolkit HtmlEditor and want to add the capability adding table to it.
How to add Table Item in toolbar?

```
%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit.HTMLEditor" TagPrefix="cc1" %>

 <cc1:Editor runat="server" Width="700px" Style="margin: 0px auto; direction: rtl;" ID="Editor" Height="500px" CssClass="ajax__htmleditor_editor_container"  
          />
```

[I have found an approach in following link](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/ajax-control-toolkit/htmleditor/how-do-i-use-the-html-editor-control-cs) but I can't add table Item.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This solution adds an "insert table button" to the AjaxControlToolKit's "Editor" control (functionality is modeled and similar to that in Microsoft Word).

> *Now, I'm not saying this is a great solution (or code for that matter), since I just quickly whipped it together -- but it should give you the solution you want, with a solid base to refactor, etc.*

---

Use the following steps to accomplish this:

**1.)Create a new class file (Extended_AjaxToolkitHtmlEditor.cs) in your App_Code folder (if the folder does not exist, create it) and paste the following code into it:**

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using AjaxControlToolkit.HTMLEditor;
using AjaxControlToolkit.HTMLEditor.ToolbarButton;

namespace Extended_AjaxToolkitHtmlEditor
{
  public class Extended_AjaxToolkitHtmlEditor : Editor
  {
    protected override void FillTopToolbar()
    {
      base.FillTopToolbar();
      TopToolbar.Buttons.Add(new AddHtmlTable_HtmlEditorToolbarButton());
    }
  }


  public class AddHtmlTable_HtmlEditorToolbarButton : MethodButton
  {
      private const string _strHtmlTableBase64Image = @"iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABYAAAAUCAYAAACJfM0wAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAADsQAAA7EAZUrDhsAAABMSURBVDhPY0xISPjPQAPABKWpDoaewQygMMYFNm/eDGVhAnxyIDOHXlCAk1twcDCUSx2wdu3a0TBGgNEwhoPRMAaDIRzGUDYVAQMDADlBXF6jlWZpAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC";
      private string _strJavaScript;

      protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
      {
        base.OnLoad(e);
        CssClass += " HtmlEditorAddTable";
        Attributes.Add("onclick", @"Extended_AjaxToolKitEditorControl.ShowTablePopUp();");
        _strJavaScript = @"<script>
var Extended_AjaxToolKitEditorControl = {
  hasBeenInitialized : false,
  divMainTable : {},
  divMainTable_ChildElements : [],


  Initialize_Elements : function(){
    Extended_AjaxToolKitEditorControl.hasBeenInitialized = true;
    var imgTableButtonElement = document.getElementById('" + ClientID + @"');
    var imgTableButtonElement_boundingRectangle = imgTableButtonElement.getBoundingClientRect();
    var divChildTableElement_toClone = document.createElement('div');
    var divSpacerElement = {};

    Extended_AjaxToolKitEditorControl.divMainTable = document.createElement('div');
    Extended_AjaxToolKitEditorControl.divMainTable.id = 'divAjaxToolKit_editorControlExtended_mainTable';
    Extended_AjaxToolKitEditorControl.divMainTable.style.background = 'white';
    Extended_AjaxToolKitEditorControl.divMainTable.style.border = '1px solid black';
    Extended_AjaxToolKitEditorControl.divMainTable.style.position = 'absolute';
    Extended_AjaxToolKitEditorControl.divMainTable.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    Extended_AjaxToolKitEditorControl.divMainTable.style.width = '220px';
    Extended_AjaxToolKitEditorControl.divMainTable.style.height = '185px';
    Extended_AjaxToolKitEditorControl.divMainTable.style.top = (imgTableButtonElement_boundingRectangle.bottom + window.pageYOffset) + 'px';
    Extended_AjaxToolKitEditorControl.divMainTable.style.left = (imgTableButtonElement_boundingRectangle.left + window.pageXOffset) + 'px';
    Extended_AjaxToolKitEditorControl.divMainTable.style.right = (imgTableButtonElement_boundingRectangle.right + window.pageXOffset) + 'px';
    Extended_AjaxToolKitEditorControl.divMainTable.onmouseleave = function() { Extended_AjaxToolKitEditorControl.HideTablePopUp(); };

    divChildTableElement_toClone.style.width = '10px';
    divChildTableElement_toClone.style.height = '10px';
    divChildTableElement_toClone.style.background = 'white';
    divChildTableElement_toClone.style.border = '1px solid black';
    divChildTableElement_toClone.style.marginRight = '5px';
    divChildTableElement_toClone.style.marginLeft = '5px';
    divChildTableElement_toClone.style.marginTop = '5px';
    divChildTableElement_toClone.style.marginBottom = '5px';
    divChildTableElement_toClone.style.display = 'inline-block';

    for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++){ Extended_AjaxToolKitEditorControl.divMainTable_ChildElements.push([divChildTableElement_toClone.cloneNode(true), divChildTableElement_toClone.cloneNode(true), divChildTableElement_toClone.cloneNode(true), divChildTableElement_toClone.cloneNode(true), divChildTableElement_toClone.cloneNode(true), divChildTableElement_toClone.cloneNode(true), divChildTableElement_toClone.cloneNode(true), divChildTableElement_toClone.cloneNode(true), divChildTableElement_toClone.cloneNode(true), divChildTableElement_toClone.cloneNode(true)]); }
    for (var rowCounter in Extended_AjaxToolKitEditorControl.divMainTable_ChildElements){
      for (var columnCounter in Extended_AjaxToolKitEditorControl.divMainTable_ChildElements[rowCounter]){
        Extended_AjaxToolKitEditorControl.divMainTable_ChildElements[rowCounter][columnCounter].id = 'newDArr_' + rowCounter + '_' + columnCounter;
        Extended_AjaxToolKitEditorControl.divMainTable_ChildElements[rowCounter][columnCounter].setAttribute('data-rowCounter', rowCounter);
        Extended_AjaxToolKitEditorControl.divMainTable_ChildElements[rowCounter][columnCounter].setAttribute('data-columnCounter', columnCounter);
        Extended_AjaxToolKitEditorControl.divMainTable_ChildElements[rowCounter][columnCounter].onclick = function(){ Extended_AjaxToolKitEditorControl.InsertHtmlTable(this.id); };
        Extended_AjaxToolKitEditorControl.divMainTable_ChildElements[rowCounter][columnCounter].onmouseover = function(){ Extended_AjaxToolKitEditorControl.SelectElementsInPopup(this.id); };
        Extended_AjaxToolKitEditorControl.divMainTable_ChildElements[rowCounter][columnCounter].onmouseout = function(){ Extended_AjaxToolKitEditorControl.UnSelectElementsInPopup(this.id); };
        Extended_AjaxToolKitEditorControl.divMainTable.appendChild(Extended_AjaxToolKitEditorControl.divMainTable_ChildElements[rowCounter][columnCounter]);
      }
      divSpacerElement = document.createElement('div');
      divSpacerElement.style.display = 'block';
      divSpacerElement.style.height = '1px';
      Extended_AjaxToolKitEditorControl.divMainTable.appendChild(divSpacerElement);
    }
    imgTableButtonElement.parentNode.appendChild(Extended_AjaxToolKitEditorControl.divMainTable);
  },


  SelectElementsInPopup : function(paramDivId){
    var divParameter = document.getElementById(paramDivId);
    var divAttributeParamRowCount = divParameter.getAttribute('data-rowCounter');
    var divAttributeParamColumnCount = divParameter.getAttribute('data-columnCounter');
    for (var i = 0; i <= divAttributeParamRowCount; i++){
      for (var j = 0; j <= divAttributeParamColumnCount; j++){
        Extended_AjaxToolKitEditorControl.divMainTable_ChildElements[i][j].style.background = 'yellow';
        Extended_AjaxToolKitEditorControl.divMainTable_ChildElements[i][j].style.border = '1px solid black';
      }
    }
  },


  UnSelectElementsInPopup : function(paramDivId){
    var divParameter = document.getElementById(paramDivId);
    var divAttributeParamRowCount = divParameter.getAttribute('data-rowCounter');
    var divAttributeParamColumnCount = divParameter.getAttribute('data-columnCounter');
    for (var i = 0; i <= divAttributeParamRowCount; i++){
      for (var j = 0; j <= divAttributeParamColumnCount; j++){
        Extended_AjaxToolKitEditorControl.divMainTable_ChildElements[i][j].style.background = 'white';
        Extended_AjaxToolKitEditorControl.divMainTable_ChildElements[i][j].style.border = '1px solid black';
      }
    }
  },


  InsertHtmlTable : function(paramDivId){
    var tableElement = document.createElement('table');
    tableElement.style.width = '250px';
    tableElement.style.height = '200px';
    tableElement.border = '1';
    var tableRowElement = {};
    var tableColumnElement = {};
    var divParameter = document.getElementById(paramDivId);
    var divAttributeParamRowCount = divParameter.getAttribute('data-rowCounter');
    var divAttributeParamColumnCount = divParameter.getAttribute('data-columnCounter');
    for (var i = 0; i <= divAttributeParamRowCount; i++){
      tableRowElement = tableElement.insertRow(i);
      for (var j = 0; j <= divAttributeParamColumnCount; j++){ tableColumnElement = tableRowElement.insertCell(j); }
    }
    var editPanelElement = document.getElementById('" + this.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.ClientID + @"').control.get_editPanel().get_modePanels()[0].insertHTML(tableElement.outerHTML);
  },


  HideTablePopUp : function(){
    var divMainTableElement = document.getElementById('divAjaxToolKit_editorControlExtended_mainTable');
    divMainTableElement.style.visibility = 'hidden';
  },


  ShowTablePopUp : function(){
    if (Extended_AjaxToolKitEditorControl.hasBeenInitialized != true){ Extended_AjaxToolKitEditorControl.Initialize_Elements(); }
    var divMainTableElement = document.getElementById('divAjaxToolKit_editorControlExtended_mainTable');
    divMainTableElement.style.visibility = 'visible';
  }
};
</script>";
      }

    protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
    {
      base.OnPreRender(e);
      var literalNewCSS = new Literal();
      var strbldrStyleElement = new StringBuilder();

      strbldrStyleElement.AppendLine(@"<style>");
      strbldrStyleElement.AppendLine(@".HtmlEditorAddTable");
      strbldrStyleElement.AppendLine(@"{");
      strbldrStyleElement.AppendLine(@"  width:23px !important;");
      strbldrStyleElement.AppendLine(@"  height:21px !important;");
      strbldrStyleElement.AppendLine(@"  margin-left:2px !important;");
      strbldrStyleElement.AppendLine(@"  background-image: url(data:image/png;base64," + _strHtmlTableBase64Image + ");");
      strbldrStyleElement.AppendLine(@"  background-repeat: no-repeat;");
      strbldrStyleElement.AppendLine(@"}");
      strbldrStyleElement.AppendLine(@"</style>");

      literalNewCSS.Text = strbldrStyleElement.ToString();
      Page.Header.Controls.Add(literalNewCSS);
      Page.RegisterClientScriptBlock("Register_Extended_AjaxToolKitEditorControlJS", _strJavaScript);
    }
  }
}
```

**2.)Then in the ASPX page, that you want to use this control, add the following at top of the file:**

```
<%@ Register Namespace="Extended_AjaxToolkitHtmlEditor" TagPrefix="extendedEditor" %>
```

**3.)Then finally in form element to the ASPX page add the control like so below:**

```
<extendedEditor:Extended_AjaxToolkitHtmlEditor runat="server" />
```

---

**Notes:**

1.)Be careful of the "aspx.designer.cs" file of the page you are adding this control to (if you are using one) -- when you put an ID on this new control element, errors get thrown.  However, if you simply remove the entry that gets added in, it will still work and remove the errors.

2.)This solution assumes you have the AjaxControlToolkit downloaded and added into your project/references already.  You can download it at: http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/

Comment: if you would use some extra local variables this code would not look so ugly.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in Javascript with an external button

```
<script type="text/JavaScript"> 

function insertTable() {
  var editor = $find("<%= myEditor.ClientID %>");
  var editPanel = editor.get_editPanel();
  var designMode = AjaxControlToolkit.HTMLEditor.ActiveModeType.Design;
  if(editPanel.get_activeMode() == designMode) {
      var designPanel = editPanel.get_modePanels()[designMode];
      designPanel.insertHTML("<table><tr><td></td></tr></table>");
  }
}
</script>
```

On the aspx page

```
<cc1:Editor runat="server" id="myEditor" />
<input type="button" value="Insert html table" onclick="insertTable();" />
```